# Angular Material design 7, component not found

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material-6

I am experienced with Angular 7 and the CLI, but new to using material design components.

I followed the getting started instructions to install and configure with Angular CLI 7.1.

I created a new module for material:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import {
  MatButtonModule,
  MatCheckboxModule,
  MatMenuModule,
  MatToolbarModule,
  MatIconModule,
  MatCardModule
} from '@angular/material';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatCheckboxModule,
    MatMenuModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatCardModule
  ],
  exports: [MatButtonModule, MatCheckboxModule, MatMenuModule, MatToolbarModule, MatIconModule, MatCardModule]
})
export class MaterialModule {}
```

I imported this module into my app module:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { LoadingBarHttpClientModule } from '@ngx-loading-bar/http-client';
import { LoadingBarRouterModule } from '@ngx-loading-bar/router';

import { AppComponent, AppRoutingModule } from '@app/index';

import { SharedModule } from '@app/shared/shared.module';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { MaterialModule } from './material.module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    LoadingBarHttpClientModule,
    LoadingBarRouterModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    SharedModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MaterialModule
  ],
  exports: [MaterialModule],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Now, I have a "home" module for my home page, as usual in our apps:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { SharedModule } from '@app/shared/shared.module';
import { HomeRoutingModule, HomeComponent } from '@app/home';

@NgModule({
  imports: [SharedModule, HomeRoutingModule],
  declarations: [HomeComponent],
  exports: []
})
export class HomeModule {}
```

Home component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html'
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {}
}
```

and then I try to add a material button to this component's html:

```
<div class="container-fluid" role="main">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col"><h1>Home</h1></div>
    <md-button>foo</md-button>
  </div>
</div>
```

But it won't compile, with the error:

```
ERROR in : 'md-button' is not a known element:
1. If 'md-button' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'md-button' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col"><h1>Home</h1></div>
   [ERROR ->]<md-button>foo</md-button>
  </div>
 </div>
")
```

I know, from experience, that something is not imported or exported somewhere, but I don't see anything in the docs to solve this.

Comment: Whats in your `SharedModule`? did you import the `MaterialModule` in your `SharedModule`? you should probably import it there instead of your `appModule` as you will be sharing it across the solution

Comment: I tried that next; same thing:  import `Material Module` and export `Material Module`.  Same error.

Comment: Try changing the exports of `MaterialModule` to the components, not the modules.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Angular Material don't have `<md-button>` component, `<md-button>foo</md-button>`That's wrong.

You have to use mat-button directive like this `<button mat-button>foo</button>`
I created the following project for a better understanding
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-byco65

for more details, Pls check: https://material.angular.io/components/button/overview

Comment: i realize that, sorry.  I was using `<mat-button>` and then in desperation I tried the older md-button

Comment: I didn't realize, do I need to use a regular HTML element and add a directive, instead of just `<mat-button>Foo</mat-button>`?

Comment: ok, that's mean you aren't importing properly, just for debugging purpose import the angular/material directly in ' HomeModule '

Comment: '<button mat-button>foo</button>'

Comment: try this `<button mat-button>Foo</button>` instead  `<mat-button>Foo</mat-button>`

Answer (score -1):

use
foo instead of using  or anyother HTML
it will work..